# Anyone have a DRYer solution to these Nested If Statements?

Tags: if-statement, dry

The purpose of this method is to the mark a user's attendance at an event. You can read it as following: If there is an event going on today, if the user exists, if his status is either subscribed or confirmed, and if this existing user has not already been checked-in, add the user to the event's user's array.

Any suggestions for a more elegant solution?

```ruby
def mark_attendance(user)
  if current_event(current_merchant)
    if user
      if user.status == 'subscribed' || user.status == 'confirmed'
        if current_event(current_merchant).users.where(id: user.id) == []
          current_event(current_merchant).users << user
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: this should probably be posted at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @EliranMalka I didn't know about codereview. I guess it's newish since it's still in Beta. My above question was less about solving this particular problem and more about just how to refactor nested if statements since I've ran into them quite often. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write something like this:

```ruby
def mark_attendance(user)

  event = current_event(current_merchant)
  attending = ['subscribed', 'confirmed']

  event.users << user if (event && user) &&
      attending.include?(user.status) &&
      event.users.where(id: user.id).any?

end
```

Not much shorted, but clearer IMO.

Answer (score 0):

my approach would be:

```ruby
def mark_attendance(user)

  if !user
    return
  end

  current_merchant_event = current_event(current_merchant)

  if !current_merchant_event
    return
  end

  if (user.status != 'subscribed' && user.status != 'confirmed')
    return
  end

  if current_merchant_event.users.where(id: user.id) == []
        current_merchant_event.users << user

  end
```

It is longer, however, there is some efficiency in execution and it is slightly easier to determine what is required to get to the 'meat' of the function.

current_event is called only once, which is what louism also indicated.

In the original code, the current_event function is called, regardless of user, which is extra code execution for no reason if user is not valid.